# How to import own scala package using spark-shell?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I have written a class for spark-ml library that uses another classes from it. 
If to be clear, my class is a wrapper for RandomForestClassifier.
Now I want to have an opportunity to import this class from spark-shell.

So the question is: how to make package containing my own class that it will be able to be imported from spark-shell? Many thanks!

Comment: Its in the first pages of the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the docs:

> [In the Spark shell, a special interpreter-aware SparkContext is already created for you, in the variable called sc. Making your own SparkContext will not work. You can set which master the context connects to using the --master argument, **and you can add JARs to the classpath by passing a comma-separated list to the --jars argument. You can also add dependencies (e.g. Spark Packages) to your shell session by supplying a comma-separated list of maven coordinates to the --packages argument.** Any additional repositories where dependencies might exist (e.g. SonaType) can be passed to the --repositories argument.](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/programming-guide.html#using-the-shell)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to import uncompiled files like `Hello.scala`, do below in spark shell:

```
scala> :load ./src/main/scala/Hello.scala
```